# Why are my measures not overlaid in dual-axis chart?

Tags: tableau-api

I have two measures, one is the actual the other is the total. I want to create a bar chart of the totals with the actual overlaid as a line. Why are they separate and not combined in my visual? I can't seem to combine them.

[image: Visual]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing step is to specify the measure you want on the dual axis. On the Rows shelf, right-click on the Balance Growth measure. Select the menu option for **Dual Axis**. That will make the dual axis chart and also give you a menu option for synchronizing the axis if you would like.

See the online help http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/multiplemeasures_dualaxes.html for more infromation.